# Как лучше реализовать коммуникацию по сети в .NET в полной связке?

Tags: c#, .net

Добрый день,

Есть программа на .Net, которая общается со своими копиями по сети с помощью "зачаток WCF".

Ближе всего это находится к топологии сети "Полносвязная". Т.е. каждая программа непосредственно связана со всеми остальными. Это нам нужно т.к. мы посылаем данные непосредственно в обход сервера. Нам нужны небольшие задержки, а сервер это лишний скачок.
Шина тоже подойдет.

На данный момент у нас есть абстрактный сервер, экземпляр который должен запускаться раньше всех, и клиенты. Это определяется настройками.
При подсоединении к серверу клиент получает адреса других подключенных клиентов и потом может уже говорить с ними напрямую.
Что происходит когда прога закрыта не интересно.

Собственно проблемы думаю ясны :)

1. прога-сервер падает/ перезагружается и все плохо.
2. Очень поздно ловим дисконнекты всех.
3. еще куча мелочей.

Хотелось бы альтернативы. Кто как решал такую проблему? Мы не можем быть уникальными :)

На данный момент есть идеи реализовать heartbeat (пакет каждую секунду и ждем ответа.) или писать жуть на UDP server/client классах.

Comment: С подобным на практике не сталкивался, но могу предложить поковырять для вдохновения DHT в торрент-трекерах и реализовать протокол обмена данными клиентах о тех соседях о которых они знают и о том, когда они их последний раз видели живыми.

Comment: WCF на дуплексном TCP-биндинге умеет отслеживать отвалившихся клиентов и сервер, причем достаточно динамично, наколенный консольный чатик реагировал мгновенно и на умерший сервер, и на отвалившегося клиента. HeartBeat - встроенный

Comment: @rdorn, А как делали если не секрет?
просто: 
[Warning](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/duplex-services)

The duplex model does not automatically detect when a service or client closes its channel. So if a client unexpectedly terminates, by default the service will not be notified, or if a client unexpectedly terminates, the service will not be notified. Clients and services can implement their own protocol to notify each other if they so choose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Жуть на UDP писать не надо, хотя UDP, безусловно, понадобится для оповещения уже работающих хостов о появлении в сети нового участника, если вы хотите полностью избавиться от сервера.

Топология "каждый с каждым" подразумевает, что сеть состоит из универсальных хостов, каждый из которых одновременно является и клиентом (может подключаться к другим хостам), и сервером (может обрабатывать подключения других хостов).

Это легко организовать на основе WCF. Для комфортной работы понадобится дуплексный канал связи, который можно организовать несколькими способами:

- [wsDualHttpBinding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.servicemodel.wsdualhttpbinding(v=vs.110).aspx) - Главный недостаток, это низкая скорость реакции на аварийные ситуации и отсутствие контроля за состоянием каналов связи. Обнаружить "упавший" хост можно только в момент обращения к нему, никаких встроенных средств не предусмотрено. Это связано стем, что он построен на основе протокола прикладного уровня HTTP, который, в общем-то, и не обязан и не может гарантировать устойчивую связь, тем более двустороннюю, не его это уровень, он выше этого =).
- [netTcpBinding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.servicemodel.nettcpbinding(v=vs.110).aspx) - высокоуровневая реализация обмена данными на основе протокола транспортного уровня TCP, который как раз и предоставляет полный контроль, поддерживает сессии, heartbeat и т.д. Данный тип привязки WCF может работать в одностороннем и двустороннем режиме в зависимости от конфигурации и реализации самого сервиса. На нем и остановимся.

Теперь разберемся с конфигурацией нашего "универсального хоста". Как было сказано выше, он должен выполнять две функции одновременно. Для иллюстрации сделаем примитивный мессенджер для локальной сети совсем без сервера ([почему только для локальной](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/717213/198316)).

Для начала научим сообщать активным участникам сети о своем присутствии и слушать вновь пришедших. Для этого понадобится совсем немного:

1. Заводим необходимые поля в классе хоста будущего сервиса (добавьте static по вкусу или необходимости)

   ```
   private readonly int port = 8888;
   private readonly IPEndPoint listenedAddress = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port);
   private readonly IPEndPoint addressForSend = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Broadcast, port);
   private readonly UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient()
   ```
2. настраиваем UdpClient

   ```
   udpClient.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
   udpClient.ExclusiveAddressUse = false; //только для работы на одной машине, в нормальных условиях не требуется
   udpClient.Client.Bind(listenedAddress);
   ```
3. Отправляем всем слушателям свои контактные данные. Так как UDP не требует подтверждения получения пакета и данных не много, используем синхронный метод.

   ```
   //адрес пока просто для примера, позже заменим на реальный
   var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("net.tcp://localhost:9995/chat");
   udpClient.Send(bytes, bytes.Length, addressForSend);
   ```
4. Включаем ожидание входящих запросов от новых клиентов. Для того чтобы не городить костыли из бесконечных циклов и Thread/Task, воспользуемся готовым асинхронным методом:

   ```
   udpClient.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), null);
   ```

   При получении входящего пакета будет вызван callback-метод, пишем его:

   ```
   private void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
   {
       //в sender попадет адрес отправителя пакета
       IPEndPoint sender = listenedAddress;
       byte[] receiveBytes = udpClient.EndReceive(ar, ref sender);
       //Это условие нужно только для работы на одной машине, чтобы не обрабатывать "эхо"
       //мы же слушаем все адреса, значит и свой тоже. Не самое красивое решение, но рабочее.
       if(sender.Address.ToString() != "0.0.0.0")
       {
           string receiveString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBytes);
           //тут позже будем что-то делать с полученными данными нового участника сети
       }
       //Ну и запускаем прослушивание заново
       udpClient.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), null);
   }
   ```

Как видите, удалось довольно красиво обойтись без "классических" `while(true)`. Больше похоже на событийную модель, со своими оговорками разумеется.

Теперь займемся непосредственно WCF компонентой. Приводить полный листинг кода тут я не буду, покажу только основные моменты, на которые стоит обратить особое внимание, т.к. в принципе WCF довольно неплохо документирован.

---

Продолжение следует...

Comment: есть еще вариант - customBinding. Можно собрать аналог wsDualHttpBinding - но с heartbeat и прочим полным контролем.

Comment: Кроме того, можно собрать полносвязанную сеть и на обычных односторонних биндингах. Надо только следить за простановкой правильного (не анонимного!) адреса отправителя в сообщениях

Comment: @PavelMayorov полностью согласен, вариантов масса, но я решил остановиться на самом простом, с максимальным использованием готовых классов

Comment: Немножко поздно, но отвечу чем закончилось. Увеличили таймауты, тк канал закрывался по неактивности и добавили heartbeat на 5 сек с проверкой. Проблема была еще в долгом таймауте когда допустим вытаскивали шнур из ноутбука или меняли сеть. Это занимало 20-70сек в зависимости от устройства. Нам это долго. Сейчас ловит за 10, что терпимо.

Comment: "Продолжение следует..." -- ping...

Comment: @andreycha спасибо, совсем забыл работой вынесло... продолжение будет сегодня ночером =)